# How tu use agreggation for grouping results?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I install ElasticSearch (6.5.0) and I'm using nest (7.0) in my project and I want for each name of a software, get all the sub-version of this software.

So I create this query :

```
var res = client
        .Search<Software>(s => s
            .Size(0)
            .Query(q => q
                 .Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.Name)
                 )
            )
            .Aggregations(a => a
                .Terms("SubVersion", t => t
                    .Field(ag => ag.SubVersion))
            )
        );

var termsAggregation = searchResponse4.Aggregations.Terms("SubVersion");
```

But the result of this query give me only the different subversion in my index.

I'm actually beginner with ElasticSearch, I already tried to find some documentation about my problem but I don't really find something that can help me.

Edit : 
To explain better, I want a query taht will give me a tree like this

`Software1
    Subversion1
    Subversion2
 Software2
    Subversion1
    SubVersion2`

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure, but on the `termsAggregation` you have the `.Bucket` property which gives you a list of KeyedBucket<> 
and the .Size(0) should be greater than 0.

```
foreach(KeyBucket<> bucket in termsAggregation.Bucket) 
{
 var key = bucket.Key;
 var values = bucket.Values; 
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: Thank for you answer. But with your code, the `bucket.key` give me the subversion and not the name.